# How to programmatically add customers to Opencart database

Tags: opencart

1. I wonder if there is a special opencart function to add/edit a
   customer to Opencart database programmatically using php/html form
   on front-end page (such as wordpress "wp_insert_post" function ) or
   I have to write all my code PHP way (insert into DB_TABLE .....)
2. Also which opencart db table(s) is used to add customer
       information with username and password

Answer (score -1):

Go to Admin `Sales->Customer` tab, from here you can add/edit your customer information.